# Waiting till the async task finish its work

Tags: android

I'm very new to programming and I have some doubts.

I have a `AsyncTask` which is I call as `RunInBackGround`.

and I start this process like:

```
new RunInBackGround().execute();
```

But I wish to wait until this call is finish its executing, before proceeding to the other statements of code.

How can I do that?

Are there any way for it?

Comment: The point of AsyncTask is that it is Asynchronous, meaning it is not synchronized with the rest of the code.

Comment: You can use its onPostExecute() of AsyncTask method to get callback in your class.

Comment: you don't really want to wait until it finished. What you want is to know when it finishes.

Comment: @DcodeChef is the only one who understood what he wanted in the question.

Comment: I think this is answer you are looking for
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079645/android-how-to-wait-asynctask-to-finish-in-mainthread

Comment: As @DcodeChef said, in the AsyncTask inherited class you can use the method onPostExecute(), and in outer classes you can have a reference to the AsyncTask and call its methods Get() or GetAsync() to wait for the synchronous/asynchronous result of the task

Answer (score 140, accepted):

> wait until this call is finish its executing

You will need to call [AsyncTask.get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) method for getting result back and make wait until `doInBackground` execution is not complete. but *this will freeze Main UI thread if you not call get method inside a Thread*.

To get result back in **UI Thread** start `AsyncTask` as :

```
String str_result= new RunInBackGround().execute().get();
```

Comment: so how to wait for the result and not get the main UI thread locked ?!
 say the code waits for the result but in the mean time, the progressbar keeps rolling !

Comment: @MuhammadNaderi: Use `AsyncTask` without `get` method and in AsyncTask `onPostExecute` method is called which provide u results on Main UI Thread

Comment: sure this is a workaround, which I have been using for a while now, but sometimes I need for the code to wait for the asynctask, something like `await` in `c#`, and not get the main thread locked of course

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK thank you, thanks a million. you have no idea how much I pulled hair over this problem however with only one .get() it solved(you kidding me) only one .get() !!!!!

Comment: How can you use the AsyncTask and avoid using the get() to avoid the UI from freezing?

Comment: @ArjunIssar: then just call `RunInBackGround().execute();` and use  `onPostExecute ` method for getting `AsyncTask ` result

Comment: For future readers, what @MuhammadNaderi wanted can be achieved by overriding `onProgressUpdate` to update the UI thread and periodically calling `publishProgress` in the `doInBackground` method to send the partial progress

Answer (score 38):

Although optimally it would be nice if your code can run parallel, it can be the case you're simply using a thread so you do not block the UI thread, even if your app's usage flow will have to wait for it.

You've got pretty much 2 options here;

1. You can execute the code you want waiting, in the AsyncTask itself. If it has to do with updating the UI(thread), you can use the onPostExecute method. This gets called automatically when your background work is done.
2. If you for some reason are forced to do it in the Activity/Fragment/Whatever, you can also just make yourself a custom listener, which you broadcast from your AsyncTask. By using this, you can have a callback method in your Activity/Fragment/Whatever which only gets called when you want it: aka when your AsyncTask is done with whatever you had to wait for.

Comment: This is a terrific answer, should be the accepted one. Also here is a sample of how to achieve this with AsyncTasks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a

Comment: in your second option, In mean time you throw intent to your receiver, the main thread will be resumed right. OP doesn't need that.

Answer (score 16):

In your `AsyncTask` add one ProgressDialog like:

```
private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
```

you can setMessage in `onPreExecute()` method like:

```
this.dialog.setMessage("Processing..."); 
this.dialog.show();
```

and in your `onPostExecute(Void result)` method dismiss your `ProgressDialog`.

Comment: ProgressDialog is deprecated years ago, don't waste your time with it, it creates an unbreakable loop in the main thread that it's impossible to destroy taking the app to memory leaks, it's even dangerous to keep it using it

Comment: AsyncTask is deprecated as well

Answer (score 16):

**AsyncTask have four methods..**

```
onPreExecute  -- for doing something before calling background task in Async

doInBackground  -- operation/Task to do in Background

onProgressUpdate  -- it is for progress Update

onPostExecute  -- this method calls after asyncTask return from doInBackground.
```

you can call your work on `onPostExecute()` it calls after returning from `doInBackground()`

**onPostExecute is what you need to Implement.**

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to create an interface to get the data from onpostexecute and run the Ui from interface :

Create an Interface :

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
    void processFinish(String output);
}
```

Then in asynctask

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String data) {
    delegate.processFinish(data);
}
```

Then in yout main activity

```
@Override
public void processFinish(String data) {
     // do things

}
```