# Calling Facebook GraphRequest from another class returns null

Tags: java, android, facebook

I'm making application that requires to get data from Facebook.
To avoid duplicating code I decided to create a class for GraphRequest.

```
public class FacebookRequest {
private static JSONObject object;

private FacebookRequest(JSONObject object) {
    this.object = object;
}

private static JSONObject GraphApiRequest(String path, AccessToken token){
        new GraphRequest(
                token,
                path,
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        object = response.getJSONObject();
                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
    return object;
}

public static JSONObject getGraphApi(String path, AccessToken token){
    return GraphApiRequest(path, token);
}}
```

To call the class I use

```
private static FacebookRequest fbRequest;
//....
JSONObject object= fbRequest.getGraphApi(path,token);
```

The problem is `GraphApiRequest` method always returns `object=null` and only after that executes request.

What should I change to get actual object on call?

**EDIT:**
Thanks to [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46844068/4601498)

So I found a solution to get object on call, but it's not perfect option (maybe even wrong, since I am not very experienced in programming, but it works for me)

```
public class FacebookRequest {
    private JSONObject object;

    public FacebookRequest(String path, AccessToken token) {
        new GraphRequest(
                token,
                path,
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        object = response.getJSONObject();
                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
    }
    public JSONObject getObject(){
        return object;
    }
}
```

When I am calling request It get's executed after some time

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    FacebookRequest fbRequest = new FacebookRequest(path,token);
    //...
}
```

To get actual object on call I use.

```
JSONObject object = fbRequest.getObject();
```

It is still not working if I call for a JSONObject **right after creating constructor**. I am looking forward to improve this code, If you will give me some advice.

Comment: You have to wait for the response (you are not waiting becouse of `.executeAsyc()`) and then use the getObject() if you want to get object *right after creating constructor*.

It can be done by replacing `.executeAsync()` with `.executeAndWait()` in `FacebookRequest`constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is explained here ([Facebook API how to wait til graphRequest executeAsync is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35905498/facebook-api-how-to-wait-til-graphrequest-executeasync-is-done)).
As you ask, for use it *right after creating constructor* replace `.executeAsyc()` with `.executeAndWait()`.

This is not adviced due a freeze on main thread and a bad user experience.

Comment: Yes @Matteo you are right I also had the same problem and I solved with this solution.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of calling.`private static FacebookRequest fbRequest;` Statically, you should call in the constructor, that way your object will not be null and in return of the response stored in object, you will receive data rather than null.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you follow https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph/ this documentation and use this method GraphRequest.newMeRequest()

Comment: What I mentioned in my question was "To avoid duplicating code I decided to create a class for GraphRequest."
I have no problems to get data in activity. 
What I want to achieve is to get JSONObject from any class, just by calling `JSONObject object= fbRequest.getGraphApi(path,token); `without making new request function.