# How to pass data from Async Class to Main Activity class

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-asynctask

I have JSON data that i converted into `JSONArray`. I have performed this conversion in an inner class which is extending `AsyncTask`.

Now i have data which contains `Images` and their `Titles`. I want to create a Loop and create `ImageView` dynamically.

The problem i am facing is that my data is in inner class and in `doInBackground()` method, and the stuff; i.e: `ImageView` i need to create is in Outer class and in `onCreate()` method.

I am unable to understand how to use `jsonArray` which i created in my `InnerClass` in my outer class.

**Inner Class:**

public class NewsService extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {

        URL url = null;
        try {
          //All JSON to JSONArray conversion code goes here
          //..

          JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
         return jsonArray;
```

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        NewsService newsService = new NewsService();
        newsService.execute();

//I need to use `jsonArray` in this part of my code
```

Comment: You want to pass JSONArray returned by doInBackground to MainActivity ?

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827532/waiting-till-the-async-task-finish-its-work

Comment: you can't use jsonArray in that part of the code. You should use it in onPostExecute instead

Comment: Yes I need to pass JSONArray to Main Activity and run loop in Mian Activity

Comment: do you actually need an asynctask to parse into json?

Comment: @PedroOliveira: what do i need to write in `post Execute` method?

Comment: That's up to you. How am I supposed to know what you want to do with your array?

Comment: @PedroOliveira : I just need to use this array in my `MainActivity`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to do this is defining an `interface` as your `AsyncTask`'s callback. Here is an example :

```
public interface Callback {
    void processData(DataType data);
}
```

and in your `MainActivity` you should `implement` that `interface` :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements Callback {
    ...
    void processData(DataType data) {
     //your code here
    }
}
```

and in your calling code :

```
new NewService(this).execute();
```

and your `NewService` class :

```
public class NewService extends AsyncTask ... {
    ...
    Callback cb;
    public NewService(Callback cb) {
    this.cb = cb;
    }
    ...
}
```

and call your `Callback` method in `onPostExecute`

```
void onPostExecute(DataType data) {
    cb(data);
}
```

Comment: of course It's better to use `WeakReference` for your `Callback` instance in your `AsyncTask` class.

Comment: Do not make the async task an inner class, but a static inner class.  This will decouple the task itself from the UI and you'll prevent activity memory leaks caused by potential configuration changes (screen rotates, user changes language, etc..).  The task can then report back using the callback system.

Comment: @Ryan I suggest to create a separate class for `AsyncTask` to re-use it anywhere you want.

Answer (score 4):

I have a number of solutions for your problem.

1. On the top what comes into my mind is that you pass the context of activity class as a data member of your async task class, then when the work is donein onPostExecute

   ((YourActivityName)context).createDynamicImages(yourJsonArray);

Before this you will need to save the context of your activity as data member of async task class

```
YourAsyncTask task = new YourAsyncTask(this);
task.execute();
```

and so the constructor of your async task class will become

```
public YourAsyncTask(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`AsynTask.doInBackground` runs on the **Background**, **Not** on the main thread, So you should use `onPostExecute` *(this method runs after the task is done)* in case you want process data on the main thread including UI updates, You can achieve that with using an `interface` inside your `AsyncTask` class:

```
    interface OnJsonArrayReceive {
    void onReceive(JSONArray array);
    }
```

`AsyncTask` class will look like this:

```
   class SomeTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONArray> {

    OnJsonArrayReceive mOnJsonArrayRecieve;

    public SomeTask(OnJsonArrayRecieve listener) {
        mOnJsonArrayRecieve = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {
        //do something with and return your array
        //this runs on background
        return jsonArray;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        //This runs on main thread
        if (mOnJsonArrayReceive != null) {
            mOnJsonArrayReceive.onReceive(jsonArray);
        }
    }
}
```

This class takes a `OnJsonArrayRecieve` listener as argument *(that is implemented in the `MainActivity`)* and when the data process on background is done `onRecieve` will be called, use it in your code like this :

```
    new SomeTask(new OnJsonArrayRecieve() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(JSONArray array) {
            //do something with json array
        }
        }).execute(someArgument);
```