# how to wait until async task finish its work?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i have this code and in  MyAsyncOpenUrl i get a jason and parse it to read server message . i store it in a public variable name message. but my problem is the if statement is running before the server message arrives. how can i wait the task until i get the message ?
by what i read  [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827532/waiting-till-the-async-task-finish-its-work) it seems i can use get method , but i dont know how to use it ?!!! :(

```
message = "";
MyAsyncOpenUrl task1 = new MyAsyncOpenUrl("http://test.com/op.php");
  try {
    task1.execute(myURL).get();
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (ExecutionException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
   }
//task1.onPostExecute(null);


if (message.equals("fail"))
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Operation faild!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example

Answer (score 0):

In tour asyncTask override method onPostExecute.

onPostExecute = your response is ready to use.

Comment: how can i give the url to onPostExecute ?

Comment: please read about asynctask http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647881/android-asynctask-example-and-explanation/25647882#25647882

Comment: thankyou Esperanz0 , but i think it is not what i am seeking for , onPostExecute cant get my url , and i dont want to change my UI layout in it , be cause i want to use it for different urls and different actions. so i just need the message :(