# How to execute the method with returned value from an asynctask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

A method is for Custom View, and Asnyctask B is for getting URL.
To load an image on Custom View with returned URL from Asynctask, I need to execute Custom View method after the asynctask.
When I call the method after asynctask, the method gets null because asynctask didnt return the value yet.
How can I handle this problem?

```java
customView= findViewById(R.id.custom_view);
UrlRequest urlRequest = new UrlRequest(this).build(); // AsyncTask
customView.loadImg(urlRequest); // null value
```

On Logcat, customView.loadImg method run first, then urlRequest is returned.

I expect the returned data, but the actual output is null...

Comment: Load Image also in this AsyncTask, it's the best way, imho

Comment: it's gonna be my last option, but I need to separate those two... haha thanks tho

Comment: Use Glide or Picasso it is far better than writing custom method. You can use an interface with an async method to get the response

Comment: you can start image loading in `onPostExecute()` of Asnyctask B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827532/waiting-till-the-async-task-finish-its-work) out. It should work the same way as `await` does in `c#`. I am not completely sure tho